# Rails 4 - Time zone display

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, time, timezone

I'm trying to make an app in Rails 4.

I have an address model, a profile model and a user model.

Address is polymorphic.

The associations are:

Address.rb

```
belongs_to :addressable, :polymorphic => true
```

Profile.rb

```
belongs_to :user

  has_many :addresses, as: :addressable
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :addresses,  reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
```

User.rb

```
  has_one :profile, dependent: :destroy
```

In my profile form, I ask users to add their address. The address form fields include an attribute to store the user's time zone.

The address form fields file has:

```
<div class="nested-fields">

  <div class="container-fluid">

                <div class="form-inputs">
                    <div class="row">
                <%=   f.country_select  :country, priority: [ "Australia", "New Zealand", "United Kingdom" ]  %>

                        </div>
              <div class="col-xs-3 col-xs-offset-1">
                <%= f.input :time_zone %>
              </div>
```

In my profiles show file I render a partial from my profiles view folder which is meant to display the time in the time zone. I tried:

```
<% if @profile.addresses.any? %>

        <%= Time.now.in_time_zone(current_user.profile.time_zone) %>
    <% else %>
        <span class="profileeditlink">
            <%= link_to "Add your location" %>
        </span>
```

When I try this, I get this error showing in the server log:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `time_zone' for #<Profile:0x007f97b35c0380>)
```

I can complete the address form fields in the profile form and submit, but the record doesn't update in the show page. If I set the time zone in the console it does update and does not display.

When I inspect the code in google, it's just an empty div tag with '...' in between.

Can anyone see what I've done wrong?

This article seems to suggest that the form of expression I used in my time zone display should work:

https://robots.thoughtbot.com/its-about-time-zones

I added this private method to my address controller just in an attempt to see if it made any difference. It doesn't (at least for this purpose). Although I can't say I've understood what it means to do.

```
  around_action :user_time_zone, :if => :current_user
def user_time_zone(&block)
  Time.use_zone(current_user.profile.time_zone, &block)
end
```

I have included strong_params in each of my address and profile controllers. I can't think of what else to check to sort this out.

My address table has:

```
t.string   "time_zone"
```

Comment: Which table has `time_zone ` column in it?

Comment: thanks - you found it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are getting the `` undefined method `time_zone' `` error because you might not have defined the field `t.string :timezone` in your migration file.

Otherwise if you do have it defined in your migration file, then run `current_user.profile.methods` to see if the `:time_zone` method is visible.

Also, make sure that your including
`<%= form_for(@instance_variable) do |f| %>` and `<%= f.submit %>` when making rails forms to ensure that data gets submitted correctly.

See: [Form for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for) and [in time zone](http://apidock.com/rails/DateAndTime/Zones/in_time_zone).

Good luck!

Comment: Hi, my address table has "time_zone" included as a string. I edited my post above to show it. I am using nested forms with cocoon gem, so have slightly different form setup for the address_fields partial.

Answer (score 0):

Im a numpty sometimes. This works.

```
<%= Time.now.in_time_zone(current_user.profile.addresses.first.time_zone) %>
```